# scheme structures and lists

Tags: list, scheme, structure, racket

```
(define-struct position (name numshares share-price))

(define p1
(cons (make-position "INT" 10 192) (cons (make-position "SSS" 4 42) 
empty)))
```

`mult` is my helper function

```
(define (mult  n)
     ( * (position-numshares n) 
     (position-share-price n)))
```

const takes the position-numshares and the position-share-price in a list and multiplies them together.

```
(define (const n)
  (cond
    [(empty? n) empty]

     [(cons? n)
       (+ (mult (first n))
                )]))
```

What I would like to do is take the first of the list and add the rest of the list together. Instead, I only get the first of the list. So if I do (const p1) I only get 1920, but I would like to get 2088 (10*192 + 4*42).  I've tried recurring for the rest, but get an error. I am probably missing something simple. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that in general, you can do

```
(list a b)
```

instead of

```
(cons a (cons b empty))
```

so you define `p1` with

```
(define p1
  (list (make-position "INT" 10 192)
        (make-position "SSS" 4 42)))
```

which is easier to read, and makes your intent clearer. Now, to get `1920` from a structure created by `(make-position "INT" 10 192)`, you've defined your helper procedure `mult`.  You can `map` `mult` over your list `p1` to get a new list of the products, i.e., `(1920 168)`.  Then you can use [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) with `+` and `0` on that list to compute its sum.

```
(define (const lst)
  (foldl + 0 (map mult lst)))

(const p1)
;=> 2088
```

If you don't want to use `fold` and `map` (which might be reasonable, since `map` means that a new list is getting allocated), you can write this out manually:

```
(define (const lst)
  (let const ((sum 0) (lst lst)) ; pretty much an implementation of fold, but 
    (if (null? lst)              ; with the function + built in, and mult applied
        sum                      ; to each element before passing to +
        (const (+ sum (mult (car lst)))
               (cdr lst)))))

(const p1)
;=> 2088
```

Another alternative would be to use `foldl`, but instead of passing `+`, pass in a function that combines `+` and `mult`:

```
(define (const3 lst)
  (foldl (lambda (struct sum)
           (+ (mult struct) sum))
         0
         lst))

(const3 p1)
```

As a Common Lisper, it's a bit disappointing to me that Scheme's `foldl` procedure doesn't take a key argument that gets applied to each element of the list before the function is applied to it.  In Common Lisp, we'd write (`foldl`/`foldr` are [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm) in Common Lisp):

```
(reduce '+ p1 :key 'mult)
```

Comment: @Josh For more information about folds, you might have a look at [this answer about flattening a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229532/1281433) and [this answer about comparing values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19006055/1281433). (Disclaimer: those are both my answers.)