# Converting a list of digits to a number

Tags: math, scheme, integer-arithmetic

I was wondering if there was a way to take a list of numbers (digits), and truncate the numbers together to be one large number (not addition) in Scheme. For example, I would want

```
(foo '(1 2 3 4))
;=> 1234
```

Does Scheme have a built in function to do this?

Comment: No, but this is a fairly easy one to implement using `reduce`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of languages that are in the Scheme family, and there are a few versions of Scheme, too.  If you're using one, e.g., Racket, that includes a left associative fold (often called `foldl`, `fold`, or `reduce`, though there are other variations, too), this is pretty straightfoward to implement in terms of the fold.  Folds have been described in more detail in these questions and answers:

- [Finding maximum distance between two points in a list (scheme)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19534355/1281433) This question includes a description of how `fold` can be viewed as an iterative construct (and in Scheme, which mandates tail call optimization, is compiled to iterative code), and also includes an implementation of `foldl` for Schemes that don't have it.
- [Flattening a List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19229444/1281433) This question is about a somewhat unusual fold, and how it (or a standard fold) can be used to flatten a list.
- [scheme structures and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19338153/1281433) This question has an example of how you might adjust the function that you pass to a fold to achieve slightly different behavior.  (I also include an opinionated (but true ;), I assure you) comment about how Common Lisp's `reduce` provides a somewhat more convenient interface than what's provided in some of the Scheme libraries.

Here's what the code looks like in terms of `foldl`:

```
(define (list->num digits)
  (foldl (lambda (digit n)
           (+ (* 10 n) digit))
         0
         digits))
```

```
> (list->num '(1 2 3 4))
1234
```

If your language *doesn't* have it, `foldl` is pretty easy to write (e.g., [my answer to the one of the questions above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19547771/1281433) includes an implementation) and use the preceding code, or you can write the whole function (using the same approach) yourself:

```
(define (list->num-helper digits number-so-far)
  (if (null? digits)
      number-so-far
      (list->num-helper (cdr digits)
                        (+ (* 10 number-so-far)
                           (car digits)))))

(define (list->num digits)
  (list->num-helper digits 0))
```

You can make that a bit more concise by using a named `let`:

```
(define (list->num digits)
  (let l->n ((digits digits)
             (number 0))
    (if (null? digits)
        number
        (l->n (cdr digits)
              (+ (* 10 number)
                 (car digits))))))
```

Comment: If I were to not use loops here (I haven't gotten to that part in my book) I would just iterate through my function until the list is null correct?

Comment: There's no "use of loops" here.  I just used the "named let" construction, and happened to use the name loop.  I'll show the version that uses a helper function, too.

Comment: In R6RS you have `fold-left` in `rnrs lists` library

Comment: In case anyone reads my comment above, I changed `loop` to `l->n` to avoid any confusion.