# how to use foldr and lambda in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am starting to learn about `lambda`.  Is there a way you can use `foldr` or `foldl` with `lambda`? Can someone give me a quick example? Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19547771/1281433) describes _how_ folds work, and links to some other answers with a bit of detail as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the squares of 3 and 4, for example:

```
(foldl 
  (lambda (val res) (+ (sqr val) res)) 
  0 
  '(3 4))
```

The initial value is 0. For each value of the list '(3 4), the function is called with the value bound to `val`, and the previous result bound to `res`.

This is equivalent to

```
(define (fun val res)
  (+ (sqr val) res))

(foldl fun 0 '(3 4))
```

except that in the first example the function is anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use lambda in combination with many things including foldl and foldr, filter, map etc (depending on what you want to achieve of course). We'll use foldr in this example.

Assuming we want to calculate the sum of all numbers in this list:

```
(define list1 '(1 2 3))
```

The syntax, using foldr and lambda would be:

```
(foldr (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 0 list1)
```

whereby:

- **(lambda (x y) (+ x y))** is our function
  (takes two parameters x and y and adds them)
- **0** is the base (meaning we start from zero, then add x and y)
- **list1** is the name of the list we are working on

Basically what we did was **(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 0)))** mathematically

Last but not least, this whole foldr function including the lambda can be shortened to

```
(foldr + 0 list1)
```

and it will pretty much do the same thing.

Here is another example, try and figure out for yourself what it does to test your understanding of the concept.

```
(foldr (lambda (x y) (append (list (add1 x)) y)) '() list1)
```