# Scheme,level intermediate student, find min without recursion

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I write a function using abstract list functions (foldr, map, and filter) without recursion that consumes a list of numbers (list a1 a2 a3 ...) and produces a new list removing the minimum number from the original list?

The recursion code is:

```
(define (find-min lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? (rest lst)) (first lst)]
    [else
     (local [(define min-rest (find-min (rest lst)))]
       (cond
         [(< (first lst) min-rest) (first lst)]
         [else min-rest]))]))
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? This looks like a homework exercise, and I fell you will learn more approaching the problem this way than if we provide code directly.

Comment: I can do it with recursion, but don't know how to do without recursion. This is not the homework question. The homework question is to calculate a grade from a list of grades without the lowest and the excused grades. I can remove the excused grades and calculate the grade. But not able to remove the lowest grade without recursion. I don't know how to get this part.

Comment: What have you done so far? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? How would *you* do it using recursion?

Comment: I tried to write the code with recursion, and tried to dig something from it but failed. I also tried to compare the first of the list with the second and then use filter, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You might find the answers to [Another way of writing a minimum value procedure in Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18996302/1281433) useful.  I bet some of them are within the syntactic restrictions that you have.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
(define (comparator n) (local [(define (compare v) (not (equal? v n)))] compare))
(define (without-min list) (filter (comparator (foldr min (foldr max 0 list) list)) list))
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't use lambda. The level is intermediate student.

Comment: Why not, you're using define which binds a lambda statement to a symbol in the current environment? My issue with this answer is that it uses the built in min function to define a min function.

Comment: The level is intermediate student only, so can't use lambda.

Comment: So we replace the lambda with a function returning a function.

Comment: One question, how can you just use min to extract the minimum of the list? It would not work.

Comment: In intermediate student, `min` seems not to be applicable to whole lists. So we need two folds more.

Comment: And in your first line of code, why there is a compare at the end.

Comment: This is intended. First, we define a function inside the function which compares its argument to the fixed value. Then, we return this function.

Comment: I am not allowed to use this I believe.

Comment: It is, indeed, a workaround for a shorter `lambda` construct. Nonetheless, intermediate student permits it.

Comment: I can't use anything beyond foldr, so I am not allowed to use this. Anyway, I will try to see if I can do it in another way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A fold applies a 2-argument function against a given value and the car of a list uses the result against the successive cars or the cdrs or the list. this is what we want.

Whereas map returns a new list by doing something with each element of a list.

And filter returns a smaller or equal list based on some predicate.

Now just to formulate a function that can choose the lessor of two arguments

```
(define (the-lessor x y)
 (if (< x  y)
     x
     y))
```

From there implementation is straightforward.

```
(define (min L) (fold the-lessor (car L) (cdr L)))
```

Comment: Usually a anonymous function would be used here though.

Comment: the-lessor should add x y as arguments or directly using lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like a homework question, I'm not going to provide all the code, but hopefully push you in the right direction.

From the [HTDP book](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/htdp-langs.html), we see that "The Intermediate Student language adds local bindings and higher-order functions." The trick here is probably going to using "local bindings".

Some assumptions:

- `(remove-min-from-list '()) => not allowed: input list must be non-empty`
- `(remove-min-from-list '(1)) => '()`
- `(remove-min-from-list '(1 2 3 1 2 3)) => '(2 3 2 3) ; all instances of 1 were removed`

Somehow, we need to find the minimum value of the list. Call this function `min-of-list`. What are its inputs and outputs? It's input is a list of numbers and its output is a number. Of the abstract list functions, which ones allow us to turn a list of numbers into a number? (And not another list.) This looks like `foldl`/`foldr` to me.

```
(define (min-of-list lst)
    (foldr some-function some-base lst))
```

Since you already showed that you could write `min-of-list` recursively, let's move on. See @WorBlux's answer for hints there.

How would we use this in our next function `remove-min-from-list`? What are the inputs and outputs of `remove-min-from-list`? It takes a list of numbers and returns a list of numbers. Okay, that looks like `map` or `filter`. However, the input list is potentially shorter than that output list, so `filter` and not `map`.

```
(define (remove-min-from-list lst)
    ....
    (filter some-predicate list))
```

What does `some-predicate` look like? It needs to return `#f` for the minimum value of the list.

Let's pull this all together and use `local` to write one function:

```
(define (remove-min-from-list lst)
  (local [(define min-value ...)
          (define (should-stay-in-list? number) ...min-value ...)]
    (filter should-stay-in-list? lst)))
```

The key here, is that the definition for `should-stay-in-list?` can refer to `min-value` because `min-value` came before it in the `local` definitions block and that the `filter` later on can use `should-stay-in-list?` because it is in the body of the `local`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out 1 min ago, I found I can just use foldr to get the minimum.