# Find minimum argument from many arguments

Tags: scheme, minimum

Let's assume we have a group of values, if we pass the values in as arguments to a function so that the function call looks like such.

```
(define (function arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7 arg8)
    ;; Return minimum argument
    )
```

How would you, without using lists or the built-in min function, and using the minimum number of comparisons find the smallest argument? I can't identify a way to do so without using lists or using a large number (in my mind) of comparisons between all of the arguments. Does Scheme have some method other than min or some syntax for efficiently finding the smallest value.

Comment: By not using lists are you suggesting that you can't use the functions `car` and `cdr` on the arguments?

Comment: There are some really smart Scheme programmers here, so I'm sure this will end up being a naive approach, but I think you are going to have to recursively call the function 8 times changing each argument to `nil` and moving the smaller of each position up until you are on the last argument.  No `min` implementation of a list of `n` can possibly be lower than `n` comparisons.

Comment: Oops, I should have said `n-1` :)

Comment: You might find [Another way of writing a mimum value procedure in Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18996302/1281433) useful or interesting, even if it doesn't provide an immediate answer.  It asks about the same kind of thing, but for four values instead of eight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know how the two argument min would be implmented, so why not just implement it locally, and then write the expansion that a list based approach would have.  That is:

```
(define (min x1 x2 x3 x4 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8)
  (define (min2 a b)
    (if (< a b) a b))
  (min2 x1 (min2 x2 (min2 x3 (min2 x4 (min2 x5 (min2 x6 (min2 x7 x8))))))))
```

That's what any approach is going to boil down to eventually.  As [malisper correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858138/1281433), you're going to need seven comparisons.

If you wanted to, you could reorder the comparisons and reduce some stack space for nested calls:

```
(define (min x1 x2 x3 x4 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8)
  (define (min2 a b)
    (if (< a b) a b))
  (min2 (min2 (min2 x1 x2) (min2 x3 x4))
        (min2 (min2 x5 x6) (min2 x7 x8))))
```

That's still seven comparisons, though.  At this point, though you're really just looking at different ways of writing the same code, in which case you should look at [Another way of writing a mimum value procedure in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18996302/1281433).

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines should work. Normally I would just loop through the arguments and keep track of the minimum seen so far, but since the arguments are taken separately this is the next best thing.

```
(define (function arg1 ... arg8)
  (let* ((best2 (if (< arg1 arg2) arg1 arg2))
         (best3 (if (< best2 arg3) best2 arg3))
         ...
         (best7 (if (< best6 arg7) best6 arg7)))
    (if (< best7 arg8)
        best7
        arg8)))
```

This uses a total of seven comparisons which I'm pretty sure is the optimal.

Comment: With `let*`, you are allowed to reuse variable names. So I'd use `best` each time.